# How to get HttpRequestContext when I am using Self Hosted Owin?

Tags: owin

How to get HttpRequestContext when I am using Self Hosted Owin?

My class is being called by ApplicationInsights and not by a controller, so I don't have access to any context.

Is there any way similar to what we do using HttpContext?

Comment: You need to provide more information. what class is being called by AppInsight? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Using the static HttpContext.Current property we can retrieve the HttpContext and the associated request from any class. But owin self host doesn't have HttpContext. So what is the alternative to get the Request data in any class?

Answer (score 0):

There is no static class to retrieve the request when using OWIN self hosted, because you are essentially in a console application, which is unaware that you wrote code that receives http requests.

Owin is a pipeline. The request is passed from middleware to middleware by calling the next middleware with a context parameter containing the request (and the response for that matter).

Each middleware registered in the pipeline can inspect the request on the way in, in their registration order, and call the next middleware before processing the response.

It is very easy to write your own middleware, register it in the pipeline, and inspect the request object for each request coming in.

Take a look here if you need a quick code example : http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps